# How to empty Windows 8 event log

Tags: windows-8, event-log

I know how to empty event log on windows XP, and then I have a script which cleans the numerous Windows 7 log categories. The windows 7 script looks like this:

> wevtutil.exe cl Analytic
>
> wevtutil.exe cl Application
>
> wevtutil.exe cl DirectShowFilterGraph
>
> wevtutil.exe cl DirectShowPluginControl
>
> wevtutil.exe cl EndpointMapper
>
> wevtutil.exe cl ForwardedEvents
>
> wevtutil.exe cl HardwareEvents
>
> wevtutil.exe cl Internet Explorer
>
> wevtutil.exe cl Key Management Service
>
> wevtutil.exe cl MF_MediaFoundationDeviceProxy
>
> ...

But the script receives access denied under windows 8 (even with Administrator account).

1- Is there a better method tho empty Windows 8 log? Or is there any way to make the script work again?

2- How is it possible to increase the event log file size in Windows 8?

Thanks.

Comment: Run the cmd as admin (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I guess in Windows 7 I had set the script to always run as administrator but forgot to do the same on Windows 8.

Comment: moving the slider in the UAC panel to the button doesn't disable the uAC in Win8. Maybe this was your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I've been using the same batch file script since Vista, and it still works fine under 8.  It's similar to yours, but does ALL the logs regardless of their name:

```
WEVTUTIL EL > .\LOGLIST.TXT
for /f %%a in ( .\LOGLIST.TXT ) do WEVTUTIL CL %%a
del .\LOGLIST.TXT
```

You will have to right-click the batch file and run it elevated ("as administrator").

2) You can enlarge individual logs by right-clicking them in Event Viewer and editing the Properties:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the short script. Yes, I guess I did not run the script as administrator.